# Find a,b,c to match the linear transformation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, linear-transformations

P.S. Sorry for my bad explanation of the task, it was really hard to translate this into meaningful english
[image]

For the given linear-transformation $A$ find all possible combinations of a,b,c for which the given matrix is a matrix of the linear transformation $A$ for a base of the polynomial space $R_2[X]$

$\left\{1,x,x^2\right\}$ Passing the standard base vectors, we get:

for $p(1) = 0$, $p(x)=1$, $p(x^2)=2x+2$

Which gives the matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&2\\ 0&0&2\\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

This is confusing, shouldn't the non-zero elements be the same?

EDIT: or should I now solve a system after setting both matrices as equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly computed 
$$
A=
[p]_\alpha^\alpha=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
where $\alpha=\{1,x,x^2\}$. You wish to find all $a$, $b$, $c$ for which 
$$
B=
[p]_\beta^\beta=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
a & 1 & 0 \\
b & 0 & 1 \\
c & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
for some basis $\beta$ for $\Bbb R_2[x]$.

One way to proceed is to note that the possible matrices for $B$ are exactly the matrices that are similar to $B$.

Note that the characteristic polynomials of $A$ and $B$ are
\begin{align*}
\chi_A(t) &= t^3 &
\chi_B(t) &= t^{3} - a t^{2} - b t - c
\end{align*}
Since similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial, we must have $a=b=c=0$.

Finally, to check that there is a basis $\beta$ for which
$$
[p]_\beta^\beta=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
we need only check that
$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]$ is similar to 
$ 
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$. Do you know how to check this?

One way to check that two matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar is:

1. check that $A$ and $B$ have the same characteristic polynomial
2. for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ and $B$ with algebraic multiplicity $m$, check that $\DeclareMathOperator{nullity}{nullity}$
   $$
   \nullity(\lambda I-A)^j = \nullity(\lambda I-B)^j
   $$
   for $1\leq j\leq m$.

In our case, to check that
\begin{align*}
A &=\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right] &
B &=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
are similar, note that each has characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(t)=\chi_B(t)=t^3$. So the only eigenvalue of $A$ and $B$ is $\lambda=0$ with algebraic multiplicity $m=3$. Now, one checks that
\begin{align*}
\nullity(-A) &= \nullity(-B)=1 \\
\nullity(A^2) &= \nullity(B^2) =2 \\
\nullity(-A^3) &= \nullity(B^3)=3
\end{align*}
This shows that $A$ and $B$ have the same [Jordan canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) and hence are similar.

Comment: I am not exactly sure on how to check if two matrices are similar my book has some theory about it, but never really show an example.